# Drizzle-Orm: How do you insert in a parent and child table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, drizzle

New to SQL... how does one insert into a parent table and a child one?

Assuming the following tables

```
import { integer, pgTable, serial, text } from 'drizzle-orm/pg-core';

export const users = pgTable('user', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
    name: text('name'),
});

export const tokens = pgTable('token', {
    id: serial('id').primaryKey(),
        userId: text("userId").notNull().references(() => users.id, { onDelete: "cascade" }),
        token: string("token"),
});
```

To create a new user with a token... I think manually looks like this...

```js
const newUser = await db.insert(users).values({name: "Billy"}).returning();
const token = await db.insert(token).values({userId: newUser.id, token: "123"}).returning();
```

Is this the proper way or is this transaction supposed to be using a view or transactions?

Comment: How about with CTEs?: `db.execute(sql``WITH sq AS (INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES 'Billy' RETURNING id) INSERT INTO tokens (userId, token) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM sq), '123')``)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that I am also pretty new to drizzle and CRUD SQL stuff, so there may be a "better" way to do this, but I believe you need to wrap this in a [transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html).

Basically, you'll return the `id` of the new user you created and use it to insert a new record in your `tokens` table (which is what you were already doing), but if an error occurs than the db "rolls back" and nothing happens.

```js
await db.transaction(async (tx) => {
  const result = await db.insert(users).values({ name: 'billy' }).returning({ userId: users.id });
  
  await db.insert(tokens).values({ userId: result[0].userId, token: '123' })
  
});
```

Comment: I don't think 'returning' is available when using Mysql.

Comment: Not sure because I don’t use MySQL, but the question is for postgres.

Comment: You can use the `insertId` from `(await tx.insert(table).values(values)).insertId`. But I don't know not it works, it is not documented...

Comment: I think acording to the documentation here: https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/transactions the correct syntax would be `await tx.insert(users)...`. Instead of `await db.insert(users)...` Not sure as  I did not see any insert example, but I think the pattern would follow